# Connecting SQL developer to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a little new at setting up this Oracle Stuff so hopefully you bear with me.

- I installed Oracle on my personal laptop and have verified running from the command prompt that it works fine. I connected using SYS as the user id and I was able to login fine
- I installed SQL developer as well

How do I setup a connection from SQL developer to Oracle? I did read the manual. What are the parameters that need to be given for the connection, the user name and the password in case I need to connect to the HR database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run SQLPlus, connect as SYS user (use administrator's password you have entered during installation) and unlock HR user and give him a new password:

```
C:\>sqlplus  sys as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Oct 19 18:10:51 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> alter user hr identified by new_password;

User altered.

SQL> alter user hr account unlock;

User altered.
```

If you are using Windows, then run firewall configuration and allow connections to TCP/IP port 1521.

Run SQL Developer and click big green "+" icon in "Connections" panel.

[image]

You will see a dialog box like below:
[image]

Fill in fields in this form like in the above picture.
SID is your database name you have entered during instalation (default is ORACL).
Click "Test" button to verify if everything is OK, if yes, then click "Save" button to remember connection's configuration, and then click "Connect".

Comment: if 12c multitenant architecture, you'll need to use the SERVICE to get to a pluggable database

Comment: @kordirko Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have the Standard Edition installed. When I try the alter user HR, I get the message the user HR does not exist.  Is this only present in the enterprise edition? If yes, can I install the Enterprise edition on my personal laptop?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I think what you said is correct. I will probably need to use service. However when I use that, I get the message ORACLE ONLY AVAILABLE TO USERS WITH RESTRICTED SESSION PRIVILEGE.             I did issue the alter system disable restricted session command but inspite of that I continue to get the same message. Any ideas?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I also needed to issue the command to alter session to pdborcl. All commands were executed successfully. I am able to query the tables within the HR schema correctly and get the desired results. Connecting from the SQL developer has been a pain. Do you have links to any documentation?

Comment: @rajeev if you don't have HR schema, then follow this link to install it: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001

Comment: there's no setup in sqldev required, it's all database configuration. what's your current problem? I'm at @thatjeffsmith on twitter and jeff.d.smith@oracle.com at work

Answer (score 0):

My pluggable database had to be force closed first and then I was able connect successfully.