# How to create a connection in Oracle-SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently installed Oracle 18c. Now I am trying to connect with SQL developer to my credentials which I gave during installation but it is not accepting and giving a message of invalid username/password; logon denied. What should I do?

Comment: reinstall it, you might have been entering the incorrect username or password. Or try changing the password [Changing password with Oracle SQL Developer](//stackoverflow.com/q/3086332)

Comment: What connection string are you using ?

Comment: System or sys user? If using sys, don't forget to set connection property from normal to SYSDBA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting SQL developer to Oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218201/connecting-sql-developer-to-oracle-12c)

Comment: which connection metho are you using? DIRECT? with Oracle Client and TNS? if it is with oracle client, what is the version of your oracle client?